# why (car ''(a b)) evaluated to 'quote?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm a beginner Scheme programmer and I want to enrich my knowledge in functional programming. I programm in DrRacket IDE. Recently I found some interesting piece of code:

```
  (car ''(a b))
```

Output:

```
  'quote
```

Can anyone explain me why is it evaluated in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `'x` (for any expression `x`) is just shorthand for `(quote x)`, so this code:

```
(car ''(a b))
```

Is equivalent to this one:

```
(car (quote (quote (a b))))
```

Now it's easy to see that you're evaluating the `car` of a list that looks like this:

```
'(quote (a b))
```

Which gets evaluated to this:

```
(list 'quote (list 'a 'b))
```

And if we take the `car` of the above line we'll get the symbol `quote`, which is precisely the result that you see printed.

Comment: we were writing at the same time? the same exact answer? :-P

Comment: @Rptx technically, you were almost a minute ahead ;)

Comment: thanx everyone for help :). It's quite simple to understand.

Comment: @Rptx yup, so it seems. You posted your answer while I was writing mine, so you're the fastest gunslinger here ;) To compensate, I expanded a bit on the explanation.

Comment: Remember though, you don't get "the symbol" `'quote`, you get the symbol `quote`.  `'quote` is *the list* `(quote quote)`.  Dr.Racket "helps" sometimes by printing a form that would produce the same value as the result, rather than the result itself.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `'` is short for `(quote ...)`. So,

`(car ''(a b))`

is actually

`(car (quote (quote (a b))))`

Which evaluates to:

`'quote`

As pointed out by Josh in the comments, The actual result is just `quote` And the REPL prints an  expression that can evaluate to `quote` in this case `'quote` or what is the same as seen above `(quote quote)`.

Comment: The *value* of `(car ''(a b))` is the symbol `quote`.  Dr Racket actually prints the abbreviated form of `(quote quote)` which is `'quote`, which is another form that evaluates to the symbol `quote`.  I think this behavior is confusing if you're not expecting it, and even more so if you're not entirely aware of the difference.  I've seen other SO askers get tripped up by it.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I know that it actually evaluates to `quote` as you correctly point out. I just wrote what the REPL prints. I prefer it as `'quote` because you can evaluate it and get the same result. I would find it confusing if it prints `quote` and I try to evaluate it and get `quote: undefined;` but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Understood.  I include the comment because often times the original asker, or people who find it later, or people who are using a different language in Dr. Racket, or a language other than Racket that still has a REPL, see something like "`(car ''(a b))` evaluates to `'quote`", but that's not the result that they get.  As far a languages with REPLs go, I think this is still fairly uncommon behavior, and it's important to be aware of it.

Comment: You are right in that also. Both guile, and mit-scheme print `quote`.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't!

```
(car ''(a b))
```

Which is

```
(car (quote (quote (a b))))
```

What happens is that `car` get evaluated to `#<procedure:car>` and since it'a procedure every argument gets evaluated **once** before applying..

```
(quote (quote (a b))) ; ==> (quote (a b))
```

Now `#<procedure:car>` of `(quote (a b))` is `quote`. It's not `'quote`. I can prove it. Try wrapping it in `display` like this: `(display (car ''(a b)))`. The output is just `quote`

**So why do you see `'quote` in racket interactions window?**

Racket has a feature that you can tweak how data is displayed when the expression results that are not explicitly printed by your program. The standard depends on the language selected and for #!racket it's to not to display the data as is but something that you can evaluate and becomes the data. In the REPL you can evaluate the output and get the same since that mode is in effect.

You can change the behaviour if you choose <kbd>Choose language</kbd> in the bottom left select and press <kbd>Show details</kbd>. The part output syntax lets you choose amongst 4 ways to "display results" in the interactions window. *print* is the language default and *write* is the same you get as when you `display` the data and what is expected from most Scheme books.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does.

Comment: @MultiTeemer Unfortunately, it **still doesn't**. What you are seeing isn't the actual evaluation but rackets way to represent data in one particular supported language in the REPL. If you had read my answer you would even have seen how to change that visualization behaviour to be exactly the same as other Scheme implementations. I don't use the default myself since it's confusing.